# .NET MAUI Command won't fire when I pass constant integer as command parameter c# markup

Tags: c#, maui, .net-8.0

I'm trying to pass an integer as a command parameter for a button command and the command isn't firing. I click and it does nothing. No exception. No compilation error. The breakpoint in my method doesn't get hit.

I am using communitytoolkit.MAUI, communitytoolkit.MVVM, and communitytoolkit.Maui.Markup, although I'm not using it in my attempts below.

I can successfully pass an entry text value.

This works in my POC app.

```
button.CommandParameter = new Binding(nameof(entry.Text), BindingMode.TwoWay, source: this);

button.BindCommand(nameof(ClickCommand), source: this, nameof(EntryText), parameterSource: this);
```

Most people use XAML, so I tried using interpreting the XAML into code:

From: [Using Command parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/commanding?view=net-maui-8.0#using-command-parameters)

```
<Button Text="5"
        Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"
        Command="{Binding DigitCommand}"
        CommandParameter="5" />
```

So, I tried:

```
getStartedButton.CommandParameter = 0;
getStartedButton.BindCommand(nameof(GettingStartedButtonClickCommand), source: this);
```

and

```
const int Step = 0;
getStartedButton.CommandParameter = new Binding(nameof(Step), BindingMode.TwoWay, source: this);
getStartedButton.BindCommand(nameof(GettingStartedButtonClickCommand), source: this);
```

and

```
const int Step = 0;
getStartedButton.CommandParameter = new Binding(nameof(Step), source: this);
getStartedButton.BindCommand(nameof(GettingStartedButtonClickCommand), source: this);
```

and

```
const int Step = 0;
getStartedButton.CommandParameter = new Binding(nameof(Step), source: this);
getStartedButton.BindCommand(nameof(GettingStartedButtonClickCommand), source: this, nameof(Step), parameterSource: this);
```

and several other variations. I hate asking for help, but I'm stumped and there's not a lot of examples using c# markup instead of XAML. I'm fairly new to .NET MAUI. This is my first time posting here, so I apologize if I am missing information or haven't formatted this properly.

I expected the integer to be passed as a parameter to the method in the viewmodel. I've tested without a parameter and it works as expected. As I described, if I bind to an Entry text value, I can get the value. It's something with how I'm passing in the constant. I've read MSDN articles, I've read SO questions. Most examples are using XAML, so I've tried converting those. I've made several attempts using different variations to see if I could even just stumble on the answer.

EDIT: I isolated the code and got it to work, kind of. I'll explain.

In the viewmodel:

```
        public void OnButtonClickCommand(string arg)
    {
```

Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Button clicked", $"The button was clicked! Args:{arg}. EntryText property: {EntryText}", "Ok");
}

In the mainpage.

```
comboControl.ClickCommand = new Command<string>(viewModel.OnButtonClickCommand);
```

In the buttoncontrol contentview.

```
    const int Step = 0;
    button.CommandParameter = 0;
    button.BindCommand(nameof(ClickCommand), source: this, nameof(Step), parameterSource: this);
```

If I have the viewmodel method as an integer and the mainpage command as integer, as I'm expecting 0 to be, it doesn't work. If I change the viewmodel to string and the new command to string, it works. Is it because the command parameter breaks it down to an object and it assumes it's a string? Is there a way to pass it as an integer into the viewmodel method so that I don't have to convert it?

Comment: Please show how you defined your command. Note that `CommandParameter="5"` will pass `5` as a string not as an integer.

Comment: @Julian I tried two different ways. getStartedButton.CommandParameter = 0; and also created an int const and passed the const to getStartedButton.CommandParameter. I was able to get it to work if I specify the passed parameter as a string (see my edit), but not as an integer. I guess I assumed it would infer it's type when it gets passed in. I'm researching if there's a way to specify the parameter type so I don't have to convert it in the viewmodel. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: In C#, `string` cannot be cast to `int`, it needs to be [parsed](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number) and that doesn't happen automatically. Since `CommandParameter` is an `object` you can pass around reference types without problems, but value types need to be cast or parsed, such as in the case of numbers *(integers, doubles, decimals, etc.)*.

Comment: @Julian Ok, I thought integers did inherit from object. That explains it then. Thank you.

Comment: In short, you'll have to convert the parameter if you use hardcoded values in XAML like `CommandParameter="5"`. If you set an integer as the `CommandParameter` directly *(in C# or via binding)*, it should work *(AFAIK)*, because the value will then get [boxed](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) into an object and then unboxed again when it's passed down to the method that is wrapped by the command.

Comment: @Julian I am doing it in code. I'm using c# markup to set the command parameter and bind the command. See my code examples above. I'm not using XAML.

Comment: Have you tried changing the signature of your command's method to `object` and then check in the debugger? BTW, integers *do* inherit from `object`, however they are a *value* type and not a *reference* type, which is why boxing/unboxing occurs.  This is unrelated to the issue of not being able to *cast* `string` to `int` - they're incompatible types.

Comment: What's the reason that you're not doing it in XAML, though? XAML is usually the easier way to go (and the more common one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. The issue was that it wasn't finding the Step const. I experimented by setting the command and method parameter to object so that it wouldn't have a conversion issue, and found that if I specified the parameter source as "this" without the parameter source path, it provided an instance of the contentview. That makes sense. Once I realized the hierarchy, I specified the name of the const "Step" as the parameter source. It passed 2. I changed object back to int in the page and viewmodel and tested and it worked. Hopefully, this will help anyone else that is trying to do this in just c#. The reason I am using declarative c# markup is for two reasons. First, it helps me understand things better. Second, it's supposed to have slightly better load times according to a video I watched with James Montemagno and a couple other people. With .NET 8 improvements, that may no longer be true.

This is in the contentview.

```
const int Step = 0;
getStartedButton.ComandParameter = Step;
getStartedButton.BindCommand(path: nameof(GettingStartedButtonClickCommand), source: this, parameterSource: Step);
```

Then, in the page.

```
decisionContentView.GettingStartedButtonClickCommand =
                        new Command<int>(setupWizardViewModel.OnStepChangedForward);
```

Then, in the viewmodel. (This isn't finished)

```
public void OnStepChangedForward(int step)
{
    var x = step;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could all be simpler perhaps, and as Julian observed the `CommandParameter` in this case *is* a `string` giving you two basic choices to make the signature match.

**SetCountCommand = new Command(onIncrementCount)**

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage() => InitializeComponent();
}
class MainPageBindingContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPageBindingContext()
    {
        IncrementCountCommand = new Command(onIncrementCount);
        SetCountCommand = new Command(onSetCount);
    }
    public ICommand SetCountCommand { get; private set; }
    private void onSetCount(object o)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Object is {o.GetType().Name}");
        Count = Convert.ToInt32(o);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

*OR*

**SetCountCommand = new Command<string>(onSetCount)**

```
    .
    .
    .
    public MainPageBindingContext()
    {
        IncrementCountCommand = new Command(onIncrementCount);
        SetCountCommand = new Command<string>(onSetCount);
    }
    public ICommand SetCountCommand { get; private set; }
    private void onSetCount(string valueAsString)
    {
        Count = Convert.ToInt32(valueAsString);
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

---

*Note: `CommandParameter` **can be** an int e.g. `CommandParameter="{StaticResource Five}"`*

---

**Maui default redux**
[image: demo]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PassIntegerAsCommandParameter"
             x:Class="PassIntegerAsCommandParameter.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainPageBindingContext/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button
                Text="Set to 5"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Sets count to 5"
                Command="{Binding SetCountCommand}"
                CommandParameter="5"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button
                Text="{Binding ButtonText}"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Command="{Binding IncrementCountCommand}"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

C#

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage() => InitializeComponent();
}
class MainPageBindingContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPageBindingContext()
    {
        IncrementCountCommand = new Command(onIncrementCount);
        SetCountCommand = new Command<string>(onSetCount);
    }
    public ICommand SetCountCommand { get; private set; }
    private void onSetCount(string valueAsString)
    {
        Count = Convert.ToInt32(valueAsString);
    }
    public ICommand IncrementCountCommand { get; private set; }
    private void onIncrementCount(object o)
    {
        Count++;
    }
    public string ButtonText
    {
        get => _buttonText;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_buttonText, value))
            {
                _buttonText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    string _buttonText = "Click me";
    public int Count
    {
        get => _count;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_count, value))
            {
                _count = value;
                if (Count == 0)
                {
                    ButtonText = "Click me";
                }
                else
                {
                    ButtonText = $"Clicked {Count} times";
                }
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    int _count = default;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```